# How to refresh fragment using Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm practice in using Navigation component. Now i have a trouble. I'm using Room database and i'm update it in my Fragment multiple times. Somehow it's anyway taking my last result no matter that i'm updating it so i decided that i need to update my fragment but i don't know how. I'm already found solutions like to detach and then attach fragment but i don't know how to do it because in my MainActivity i'm attaching to my fragment through "setupActionBarWithNavController".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating matters. If you are using Room to manage your data, and the values in the database are getting updated by your code, then you can simply use `LiveData`. You don't need to reload your fragment at all.

Have your Room DAO query return a `LiveData<MyType>` instead of just a `MyType` object (for example). You can then "observe" the `LiveData` in your Fragment, and write a callback function to update your UI every time the value returned by the query changes. See [this page](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47) for more info.

This basically means that when you tell your model to `updateInsulin`, once the database value is changed, the LiveData watching your insulin level will change and trigger your `Observer`. The `Observer` can then do something like change the text of a `TextView` or naviagte to a different Fragment.

Comment: Thank you. I already heard about LiveData but never used this. I think it's time to learn it :)

Comment: can you help me to write this thing? I can't understand how can i do it :( If you want i can give you my repository link or maybe i will show in discord or something. I just want to know how can i do it but i can't :(

Comment: I have a similar problem, and am already using LIVE data, but I don't know how to do the step "update your UI".  My layout is a fragment displayed with the navigation component.  Can someone please tell me how to refresh the View from my observed data callback?